# Reproducing CSS3 webkit transition and transform in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, transform, transition

I'm trying to make a simple 'cloud of links', some 5 or 6 links distributed randomly with absolute positioning. When hovering, they scale (from the center of the object, not from top left) to a larger size smoothly, shrinking back on mouseout.

That's perfectly doable using CSS3 transformations and transitions, but I need a solution that  also works in IE8+. The target audience for my website is the kind of people that uses whatever comes out of the box, hence the IE bother.

I'm open to any suggestions. Javascript, Jquery, Mootools, Prototype... name it, and I'll try it.

Comment: you'd have been better off using `internet-explorer` tags rather than `jquery` and `mootools`. Tag a question based on the problem, not on your thoughts about a possible solution.

Answer (score 6):

IE9 and IE10 support CSS3 transforms anyway, so no need to worry about that. (you'll need to use `-ms-transform` for IE9).

You can see the browser support charts for CSS transforms here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

IE8 doesn't support CSS transforms, but there are ways around it. For IE8 I recommend using [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/#more-896).

This is a javascript library that implements CSS transforms and other features into IE8 and earlier.

You can then use syntax that looks like this:

```
-sand-transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: great! I'm checking it out. Does it support the CSS -transition as well?

Comment: @FelipeGarciaRijo - sorry, I'm fairly sure it doesn't do transisions. I would expect them to be a *lot* harder to achieve in Javascript, especially when combined with transforms. I'm afraid I have my doubts about whether you'll find any solutions to that.

Comment: Well, the transform itself already solves the problem of the scale. If they can't see it, they should stop using IE.